# I need to assign populations (denominators) to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rate, population, adjustment

I need to assign populations (denominators) to a data frame in R. For each age group and each year, the populations are different.
My data frame is

```
Year agegroup count
2000 0-4 24
2000 5-9 36
....
2021 0-4 42
2021 95+ 132
```

How can I assign each year and age group (row) a different population?

I don't know how to do it, can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you please say more about what you mean by populations / denominators? What would the expected output look like?

Comment: Where are the populations supposed to come from?

Comment: Probably using a `merge` or `join` operation. Can you show us a sample of the population denominator inputs and show the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
I have this data frame:

> head(pop)
> Year    Age_group   Count   Population
> 1:00    1993        7   12
> 2:00    1994        7   18
> 3:00    1995        7   14
> 4:00    1993        8   16
> 5:00    1994        8   26
> 6:00    1995        8   27
> 7:00    1996        8   21
> … Continue

And I want to put in the populations column the data that I have in another dataframe, so that the result is this:

> head(pop1)
> Year    Age_group   Count   Population
> 1:00    1993        7   12     133404
> 2:00    1994        7   18     155638
> 3:00    1995        7   14     100053
> 4:00    1993        8   16     211223
> 5:00    1994        8   26     111170
> 6:00    1995        8   27     255691
> 7:00    1996        8   21     255691
> … Continue

Comment: You are posting this information as an answer. Instead **edit** the question, use the edit link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Hi Enrique. Welcome to the stack, and do take the [tour] if you haven't already. Please don't post additional details/code as answers to the question - our format is not the same as other forums. You should delete these answers and edit your question to include these details. Answers are solely for answering. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have this data frame:
Year agegroup count
2000 0-4      24
2000 5-9      36
....
2021 0-4      42
2021 95+     132

And I want to put in the populations column the data that I have in another dataframe, so that the result is this:

Year agegroup count population
2000 0-4      24     123500
2000 5-9      36     132600
....
2021 0-4      42     145200
2021 95+     132     187540

Comment: Hi Enrique. This is not an answer to the question, so should not be posted as an answer. Please take the SO [tour] if you haven't already.